# Saving values of debug session from watch window to a file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have to trace some events I want to trace to monitor the operation of a multi-threaded application. For this purpose I defined an array of structs. Each element is one trace record.

```
enum Event { start, stop, pause };
struct A
{
    Event e;
    int x, y, z;
};

main()
{
  A a[100];
}
```

There is also a function the writes the event to the array. The array `a` can be displayed in the watch window of Visual Studio, although not all struct members are displayed:

```
-       a               0x008ff4bc {{e=0xcccccccc x=0xcccccccc y=0xcccccccc ...}, {e=0xcccccccc x=0xcccccccc y=0xcccccccc ...}, ...}    A[0x00000064]
+       [0x00000000]    {e=0xcccccccc x=0xcccccccc y=0xcccccccc ...}    A
+       [0x00000001]    {e=0xcccccccc x=0xcccccccc y=0xcccccccc ...}    A
+       [0x00000002]    {e=0xcccccccc x=0xcccccccc y=0xcccccccc ...}    A
```

Since the array is rather large and the limitation of the watch I want to export the entire array content to a file. This could be done by adding a file export function to the code that is being debugged. But this is no handy, since the debugger is just in a breakpoint and it's not always possible to tell the application to run the export function.

How can I export the array with the values of **all** members? Is there an option to use the VS command window or probably immediate window to create a text file with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a one-click export? You can select all, copy and paste into your output file. You can do it from `Watch` window, but the output is a bit more clear from either `Immediate` or `Command` windows.

You can beautify the format by creating a custom visualizer in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` (use *your* version of the VS).

Here is how it may look, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="A">
    <DisplayString>({e}:{x},{y},{z})</DisplayString>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Comment: Is there any chance to send the `Immediate` or `Command` output directly to a file instead of using the clipboard with Copy&Paste? This would be helpful because of the array size.

Comment: There has to be a way via automation (by writing a VS extension?). The `IVsCommandWindow` interface has a method `LogToFile`; looks like it will do what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivscommandwindow.logtofile?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: How do you use the IVsCommandWindow automation object from the `Immediate` or `Command` window?

Comment: I’m afraid you have to write an extension fonVS